# How to convert hierarchy nested array to separate select inputs?

Tags: php, html

I have the following nested array, where each level represents an hierarchy that should be a value of select with regards to its hierarchy. (Each nesting level has a value that represents its parent id)

Example data:

```
$data = [
  "group1" => [
        "group_id" => 0,
        "subgroup1" => [
            "subgroup_id" => 0,
            "unit1" => [
                "unit_id" => 0,
                "subunit1" => [
                    "subunit_id" => 0
                ],    
            ],
            "unit2" => [
                "unit_id" => 1
            "subunit2" => [
                "subunit_id" => 1
            ],        
        ],     
    ],
    
    "subgroup2" => [
        "subgroup_id" => 1,
        "unit3" =>  [
            "unit_id" => 2,
            "subunit3" =>  [
                "subunit_id" => 2
            ],        
        ],
        "unit4" => [
            "unit_id" => 3,
            "subunit4" => [     
                "subunit_id" => 3
        ],       
      ],      
    ],    
  ]
```

And I want to create separate select for each nesting level:

```
<select>
    <option>group1</option>
    <option>group2</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option class="group_id_0">subgroup1</option> //group_id refers to the parent group id
    <option class="group_id_1">subgroup2</option>
</select>
```

I've tried doing it in a nested for each loop but I couldn't do it because the selects are separate

Comment: Your `$data` array feels very hand-made and the key names aren't very consistent.

Comment: _I couldn't do it because the selects are separate_ So put data into variables rather than output it directly. Then output the selects after you have all the data picked

Comment: Its never a bad idea to show us the code you have, if nothing else it is more descriptive of your issue than a long description

Comment: Guys sorry you're correct I had alot of mistakes when I tried to convert my actual data to similar data. The problem is it's in other language. This time I converted it correctly and more consistently

Comment: Where's group2 now? Anyway, I think the way you ask this question makes it very hard for us to help you. You want selects, there's some relationship between them, and you want to store that relationship in an array. I get that bit. What I don't get is what the relationship between the selects is. So your question should start with explaining that relationship, show us some real selects, and then the way you tried to code it. Basically the other way around than you currently have. But for now I am voting to close this question due to lack of clarity.